# Perl - Regex escaping failure

Tags: regex, perl

Following Perl onliner fails, the regex is ok, though. Something is wrong with the esacping, but I can't finger out what. Can someone help me out? I'm on Linux/Bash.

```
perl -pi -e '(?<=\.zip).*?(hren)|(^\")|(^\r\n|^\n)|(^New).*?(\")|(\,\s)' file
```

This is the error message:

```
Unmatched ) in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/<=\.zip) <-- HERE .*/ at -e line 1.
```

Comment: Technically you don't have a regex (no `m//` nor `s///`).

Comment: @mpapec, he does, just not the one he thought!

Comment: @RobEarl yes, perl is once again trying to make sense out of it. `:)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @mpapec pointed out, you forgot to add `m//` to make the statement into a regex. So why do you get a regex error if it isn't being treated as a regex?

Perl thinks you're trying to use the `?PATTERN?` format for pattern matching, see [perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#?PATTERN?msixpodualgc). It looks at:

```
?<=\.zip).*?
```

Attempts to interpret the bit between `?..?` as a regex and correctly identifies the unmatched `)`.

Comment: Probably it got confused by the missing m//.
This one works: perl -pe 's/(?<=\.zip).*?(hren)|(^\")|(^\r\n|^\n)|(^New).*?(\")|(\,\s)//g' file